# nested resources with form_for losing first id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for, nested-routes

This is a strange error that has really got me bugged. First, some background.

I have the following nested resources in my config/routes.rb:

```
scope :requirements => { :protocol => 'https' } do
    resource :user
    resources :orgs do
        resources :members
        resources :events
        resources :levels
        resources :attendances
    end
    resources :sessions,    :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Then, in app/controllers/levels_controller.rb I have:

```
def edit
    @org = Org.find(params[:org_id])
    @level = OrgLevel.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @level = OrgLevel.find(params[:id])
    if @level.update_attributes(params[:level])
        flash[:success] = "Level details updated"
        redirect_to @level
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Finally, in app/views/levels/edit.html.erb, I have:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit #{@level.name} for #{@org.name}") %> 
<div class="hero-unit">
    <h2>Edit &quot;<%= @level.name %>&quot; membership level for <%= @org.name %></h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <%= form_for [@org, @level], :url => org_level_path do |f| %>
                <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                <table class="editor">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label_x">
                            <%= f.label :name %>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <%= f.text_field :name %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result of calling https://spot-macbook.local/orgs/55/levels/162/edit is normal, but clicking "Save Changes" results in a redirection to https://spot-macbook.local/orgs/162/levels/162 and the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LevelsController#show

Couldn't find Org with id=162
Rails.root: /Users/ogod/Projects/rails_projects/nom_de_joye_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/levels_controller.rb:71:in `correct_user'
Request

Parameters:

{"requirements"=>{"protocol"=>"https"},
 "org_id"=>"162",
 "id"=>"162"}
```

Note that the org_id has changed to "162" instead of "55". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

Five seconds after I post this question, I realised there error and corrected it.

The original has the update method with the following:

```
    redirect_to @level
```

This should be:

```
    redirect_to org_level_path(@org, @level)
```

Such a simple error, but I was looking in the wrong place!

Comment: Thank you!  The nested resources path syntax with (parent, child) gets me every time...